# Compatibilidad con Firefox e IE con el objeto Date() - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quería pediros ayuda con un código de Javascript de un reloj cuenta atrás, con el objeto date, que me da problemas retornando NAN con dos navegadores, con IE y con Firefox, (con Safari también me daba, pero pude solucionarlo); Muchas gracias por adelantado!

```js
const second = 1000,
      minute = 1000 * 60,
      hour = 60000 * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date('Jan 01, 2020 00:00:00'.replace(/\s/, 'T')).getTime(),

w = setInterval(function() {
    let now = new Date().getTime(),
    distance = countDown - now;

    document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor((distance / (day))),
    document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
      
}, second);
```

```html
<!-- reloj -->
                    <ul class="liss col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="head">
                            <h2>cuenta atras</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="liss2 row">

                            <li class="lireloj col-4">
                                <div id="days"></div>
                                <div class="days">Days</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="lireloj col-4">
                                <div id="hours"></div>
                                <div class="hours ">Hours</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="lireloj  col-4">
                                <div id="seconds"></div>  <div class="seconds ">Seconds</div>
                            </li>

                        </div>

                    </ul>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código `html` necesario para crear un [Ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Y así probarlo en diferentes navegadores.

Comment: Cual es el motivo de: `.replace(/\s/, 'T')`  ? Estas remplazando el primer espacio en blanco por una `T`, y entonces obtienes este resultado: `JanT01, 2020 00:00:00` por lo cual es una fecha no valida.

Comment: para hacerlo compatible con safari...

Comment: Pues es justo ahi donde esta el error, te recomiendo que solo hagas uso de `replace` cuando sea un safari o usar [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @ElenaMenéndez-Ormaza, ¿por que es necesario hacer `'Jan 01, 2020 00:00:00'.replace(/\s/, 'T')`? ¿Esa cadena viene de otro lado o se puede modificar sin problema?

Comment: muchasss gracias!!! si estuve cambiando a raíz de esto... que me comentaís ...y lo solucionamos, gracias por la ayuda!